# Need help with REST Query against Task List

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-foundation, rest, csom

Our O365 Site has come crawling to a snail's pace, after speaking with Microsoft Support they have told me the OOBE Web Parts are causing the speed issue and that I need to use CSOM or REST Queries to display the data and not slow the site down.

I have no idea how to do this or where to start. BUT - I want to learn. Currently I display 5 Tasks Lists on the home page that their views are filtered to display tasks assigned to [Me]. Microsoft says this is my issue as these lists each contain over 3000 items.

Can someone point me in the right direction or provide some real-world examples so I can speed our site up again?

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you need to be able to show your users a listing of all the tasks they have open, from a number of SharePoint lists.

Use a Content Search Web Part for this.  It enables you to grab all tasks from all lists in your environment and show them in a single web part. It will perform much better than your current approach. It also scales better (i.e, what happens when you add a sixth task list?).  It's also much simpler to set up and maintain that a code-based approach.

http://www.sharepointnutsandbolts.com/2012/10/using-content-search-web-part-and.html

One more thing, be careful about solutioning advice from Level 1 Office 365 support.  These guys are not really experts; their goal is not to solve your problem, it is to close the ticket.

Comment: Also look into what Fields you query and maybe put an Index on those to speed things up